# Сжать по высоте содержимое 'content', изменить цвет <summary> в открытом состоянии

Tags: html, css, content

Подскажите пожалуйста:
1. Как мне сжать по высоте содержимое `content: "\02C5";`. В идеале данная стрелка должна быть такой же по ширине и по высоте раза в два-три меньше.
2. Как сделать, чтобы заголовок `<summary>` в активном (открытом) состоянии был другого цвета?

[Код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sczwr6L7/)

Спасибо!
[image: Вопрос с summary и content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер стрелочки регулируется через font-size у `.periods-title::after`

А цвет заглавления меняет `.periods[open] .periods-title {color: ...;}`

```css
.periods {
  display: block;
  max-width: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D2D9E2;
}

.periods-title::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.periods-title::-moz-list-bullet {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.periods-title::marker {
  display: none;
}

.periods-title {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0059D9;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.periods-title:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.periods[open] {
  color: #000;
}

.periods-title::after {
  content: "\02C5";
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: scaleY(0.5);
  color: #0059d9;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.periods[open] > .periods-title:after {
  transform: scale(1, -0.5);
}

.periods-title ~ * {
  padding: 0 1em 10px 1.4em;
}

.periods[open] .periods-title {
  color: #f36700;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.periods[open] .periods-title ~ * {
  animation: sweep 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color: #000;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.periods-title:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.periods-description {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 180px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<details class='periods'>
  <summary class='periods-title'>Title</summary>
  <p class='periods-description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Velit impedit facilis distinctio tenetur, corporis excepturi.</p>
</details>

<details class='periods'>
  <summary class='periods-title'>Title</summary>
  <p class='periods-description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Velit impedit facilis distinctio tenetur, corporis excepturi.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Да, я знал, что за это отвечает font-size, но при его изменении стрелочка меняется пропорционально, а мне было интересно можно ли ширину оставить, а изменить только высоту. Хотел обойтись малой кровью и использовать тут content, но, возможно, он для таких целей не подходит.
За изменение цвета - спасибо!

Comment: @kan Да, тот же `transform: scale` ) В начальном виде добавил scaleY(0.5) а в открытом `scale(1, -0.5)` вместо -1

Comment: оно! да! благодарю!

Comment: @kan или, вместо символа - туда можно добавить любую удобную картинку - хоть котика)) `content: url('ссылка');`

Comment: котику я цвет при активности не задам))  
задумка была, что в спокойном состоянии стрелочка одного цвета, а в открытом стрелочка другого цвета.  по этой причине решил content использовать вместо, `background: url()`

Comment: url можно разные прописать) Для стандартного состояния одно, для [open] - другое.

Comment: Думал, что с content меньше будет геморроя, если честно)

Answer (score 0):

1) Через свойство `content` псевдоэлемента задаётся текст. А высоту текста можно поменять, изменив его размер. Задайте для `.periods-title:after` свойство `font-size` меньше.

2) Чтобы изменить цвет элемента `summary` в открытом состоянии, укажите это условие через обращение по атрибуту элемента `details`

Результат
https://jsfiddle.net/8a5eotzp/1/

```css
.periods {
  display: block;
  max-width: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D2D9E2;
}

.periods-title::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.periods-title::-moz-list-bullet {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.periods-title::marker {
  display: none;
}

.periods-title {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0059D9;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.periods-title:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.periods[open] {
  color: #000;
}

.periods-title:after {
  content: "\02C5";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.periods[open]>.periods-title:after {
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}

.periods-title~* {
  padding: 0 1em 10px 1.4em;
}

.periods[open] .periods-title~* {
  animation: sweep .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #000;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.periods-title:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.periods-description {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 180px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.periods[open] .periods-title {
  background: #ccc;
}


}
```

```html
<details class='periods'>
  <summary class='periods-title'>Title</summary>
  <p class='periods-description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Velit impedit facilis distinctio tenetur, corporis excepturi.</p>
</details>

<details class='periods'>
  <summary class='periods-title'>Title</summary>
  <p class='periods-description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Velit impedit facilis distinctio tenetur, corporis excepturi.</p>
</details>
```